# Java - Convert JSON to XML keeping the attributes

Tags: java, json, xml

Using the org.json json library, it's easy to convert from XML to JSON. but the conversion back to XML always convert JSON attributes into XML nodes:

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.XML;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String xml = "<tag1 attr1=\"val1\"><tag2 attr2=\"val2\"/></tag1>";
        System.out.println(xml);

        JSONObject str = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        System.out.println(str);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str.toString());
        String xml2 = XML.toString(json);
        System.out.println(xml2);
    }
}
```

Output

```
<tag1 attr1="val1"><tag2 attr2="val2"/></tag1>
{"tag1":{"attr1":"val1","tag2":{"attr2":"val2"}}}
<tag1><attr1>val1</attr1><tag2><attr2>val2</attr2></tag2></tag1>
```

How can I retrieve my XML attributes?

Comment: Have you looked at [Badgerfish](http://badgerfish.ning.com)? It's a convention for translating XML to JSON and back again. Might work for you if you don't mind having weirdness in your JSON.

Answer (score 6):

[Underscore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) has static methods `U.xmlToJson(xml)` and `U.jsonToXml(json)`. [Live example](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/H8B)

```
import com.github.underscore.U;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<tag1 attr1=\"val1\"><tag2 attr2=\"val2\"/></tag1>";
        System.out.println(U.xmlToJson(xml));
        System.out.println(U.jsonToXml(U.xmlToJson(xml)));
    }
}

// {
//   "tag1": {
//     "-attr1": "val1",
//     "tag2": {
//       "-attr2": "val2",
//       "-self-closing": "true"
//     }
//   },
//   "#omit-xml-declaration": "yes"
// }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would convert below XML

```
<tag1><attr1>val1</attr1><tag2><attr2>val2</attr2></tag2></tag1>
```

you would get the same JSON result;

```
{"tag1":{"attr1":"val1","tag2":{"attr2":"val2"}}}
```

so converting back from JSON to XML could cause an ambiguity. Therefore it is better to write some custom codes indicating that if a json field and an attribute or a tag. I'm not sure if there is a library for that converting but this link might be helpful;

http://www.cubicrace.com/2015/06/How-to-convert-XML-to-JSON-format.html